# How can we say “take control” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How can we say “take control” in Latin?

"Take control" like a motto that implies taking control of the situation, yourself, your life etc.

Google translate gives UT IMPERIUM

I've also seen a CARPE IMPERIUM

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Latin nouns that mean control, each one meaning a slightly different form of control. 'imperium' usually pertains to control of an empire, kingdom or army, I believe.

I would venture 'moderatio', referring to moderation and self-control, or 'dicio', meaning authority/power over something else.

'carpere' means 'to take', as in, to pluck or to seize.

So perhaps,

> carpe dicionem

'carpe' is singular imperative, which works fine for addressing yourself. Were it a slogan that you wished to use with a group of people the plural imperative would be needed:

> carpite dicionem

I hope this helps! I am sure more experienced Latinists will be along shortly to offer their suggestions.

Comment: Very instructive. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user10034 Please allow time for more answers. [_Carpe_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=carpo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) primarily means to pluck, as a fruit or a flower. It has many extended senses, but the famous line _Carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero_ means, in clumsy but clear English, "Enjoy the day (like a berry), trusting (gullibly) to the next day as little as possible." The [whole poem](https://thebookbindersdaughter.com/2018/04/30/may-you-strain-your-wine-horace-ode-1-11/) advises sweet pleasures over future concerns. Maybe not the tone you want.

Comment: @BenKovitz A good point! Perhaps 'capere' would be a more suitable choice; this has connotations of forceful taking if I am not mistaken. So maybe "cape dicionem"?

Comment: Yes, to me _cape_ sounds more in the spirit. I also wonder if the Latin mind might have a wholly different metaphor for this than speaking of control as an object that you can take (as excellent a metaphor as that is). Maybe there is even a proverbial expression for it. I'm thinking especially that since the main idea is action, Latin would express the main idea in a verb, making it stand out pretty forcefully, e.g. _Dūce, nōn dūcere._

Comment: What do you think of "Imperare Sibi" from "Imperare sibi maximum imperium est" (To rule yourself is the ultimate form of power), the quote by Seneca?

Comment: @InOmniaParatus Ille mihi videtur dignum est in alterum responsum proponere! Responsum a Seneca bonum semper est.